# SQL 特定の日付における特定の時間帯のデータを取得する方法

Tags: sql

例として、1月1日から１月2１日までの５時から9時３０分だけのデータを取得したい場合、どのようにWHEREをかけばよろしいでしょうか？
以下のようにHourを指定するだけならとくに問題ないのですが、9時から9時半の時間帯をどのように取得するのかがわかりませんでした。Minutes(timestamp) between 0 and 30としてしまうと5時などのデータまで影響をうけてしまいます。

```
SELECT
XXXX

FROM
YYYY

WHERE 1=1
 AND date(timestamp) between date('2021-01-01') and date('2021-01-21')
 AND hour(timestamp) between 5 and 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> WHERE 1=1
>  AND date(timestamp) between date('2021-01-01') and date('2021-01-21')
>  AND hour(timestamp) between 5 and 9
> ```

`date()`と同様に`time()`を使うだけではないでしょうか？

```
WHERE 1=1
 AND date(timestamp) between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-21'
 AND time(timestamp) between '05:00:00' and '09:30:00`
```

Comment: すいません、簡単にとれるのですね。ありがとうございました。